# How to write Hazelcast Jet job to process Http request and emit result as response

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I have an http endpoint where client make request with their data to which a computed response is returned. The computation has few stages - `data lookup`, `calculations` & few `transformations`. The final result is written as response to the request.

Can I write a Hazelcast Jet job that takes in data received in the http, does all computation defined above & respond back the result to the request?

I see no straight way this, however, one approach I see is, have a reactive http-server, read the request in reactive way, write the request to `Ringbuffer` or `IQueue` & wait for the result (with help of a callback) in the other `Ringbuffer`.

A Hazelcast job can read from the source `Ringbuffer`, computes & transforms, finally writting the result to another `Ringbuffer` (sink).

Does Hazelcast Jet used such a way? Your thoughts can help to understand Jet better.

Comment: I imagine this is a reasonable way to use Jet. It should be running an unbounded streaming job where each request is just one input item in it. This should allow you to achieve excellent resource usage and throughput. The Hazelcast Jet project doesn't yet have a demo or code sample implementing this, however.

Comment: Can you point me to some resources?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to add a web layer: as you would need to write an HTTP endpoint to start the Jet Job, it can send the response once the Job is finished.

You can do it blocking/reactive/whatever, but the logic is the same.

Comment: So, if I understood your statement, the request reader triggers the job and post the job finish respond with the result.

Comment: That's what I would do it. Separation of concerns, and all.